# Implementing Boundary Value Analysis of Software Testing in a C++ program?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
         int n,a[n],x,c,u[n],m[n],e[n][4];
         cout<<"Enter the number of variables";
         cin>>n;

         cout<<"Enter the Lower, and Upper Limits of the variables";
         for(int y=1; y<n+1; y++)
         {
                 cin>>m[y];
                 cin>>u[y];
         }
         for(x=1; x<n+1; x++)
         {
                 a[x] = (m[x] + u[x])/2;
         }
         c=(n*4)-4;
         for(int a1=1; a1<n+1; a1++)
         {

             e[a1][0] = m[a1];
             e[a1][1] = m[a1]+1;
             e[a1][2] = u[a1]-1;
             e[a1][3] = u[a1];
         }
         for(int i=1; i<n+1; i++)
         {
            for(int l=1; l<=i; l++)
            {
                 if(l!=1)
                 {
                    cout<<a[l]<<"\t";
                 }
            }
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
            {
                cout<<e[i][j];
                for(int k=0; k<n-(i+1); k++)
                {
                    cout<<a[k]<<"\t";
                }
                cout<<"\n";
            }
        }    

        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;    
}
```

The answer should come in the form of a table like

```
       1            50              50
       2            50              50
       99           50              50
       100          50              50
       50           1               50
       50           2               50
       50           99              50
       50           100             50
       50           50              1
       50           50              2
       50           50              99
       50           50              100
```

if the no of inputs is 3 and their ranges are
1,100
1,100
1,100
(could be varied too)

The output is not coming,can anyone correct the code or tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what's working and what not?  What errors? Don't just dump code and expect us to do all the work for you.

Comment: Dude, your code formatting is terrible!! Can't you make it a bit more readable??

Comment: I wrote the code, sir. The table is not coming as expected?

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand your problem. Your title is not descriptive enough. There are many guys out there that would help you, but could you please tell us what's going wrong and what the program is supposed to do actually.

Comment: It accepts number of variables and their ranges, i.e the maximum and minimum values those variables can get. Then it performs bpundary value analysis and prints the output like the table shown. Minimum value, maximum value, min value + 1, max value + 1, nominal value.   maybe this link can make you understand                                                       http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary-value_analysis

Comment: How does that even compile? the first line (with the declarations) does not seem valid to me with n not being a constant known at compile time.

Comment: @Asaf: It's actually a (horrible) gcc extension.

Comment: @kbok: (original comment deleted) Never mind. I read your answer. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Asaf: No offense taken. These "arrays" reserve the required space in the stack, pretty much like a regular array would, except that the space required is computed just before the alloc(kind of like what `alloca()` does.) And yes, the value of `n` is determined later in the program, but that doesn't keep your compiler from using it right now. That's right, in this program the arrays have a size possibly between INT_MIN and INT_MAX :)

Answer (score 2):

I won't dive into your code, but I can point you to some mistakes in your code :

`int n,a[n],x,c,u[n],m[n],e[n][4];`

- These arrays, where the size is a local value, are called VLAs (Variable-Length Arrays) and are an extension to C++. Don't use them.
- At the declaration of the arrays, `int n` has not yet been initialized (it is from user input two lines later). Thus, all these arrays have an invalid size.

`for(int y=1; y<n+1; y++)`

- For an array of size `n`, the valid indexes range from `0` to `n-1`.

`system("PAUSE");`

- This is very platform-specific, and can be quite annoying in some cases. Prefer asking for a keystroke with `std::cin`.

---

Generally speaking, if you are using C++, you should drop the use of old-school C arrays. Prefer the nice data structures that the standard library offers you, such as `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::deque`, or the C++11 `std::array`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comments sir, but actually what iam asking is , that if the code written after all the declarations correctly prints the table? Is it logically correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your code is very difficult to understand in its actual state. I suggest that yo use more explicit names for the arrays, and remove some of the intermediary results, such as the arrays `a[]` and `e[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
         int n,a[3],x,c,max[3],min[3],e[3][4];
         cout<<"Enter the number of variables";
         cin>>n;

         cout<<"Enter the minimun, and maximun Limits of the variables";
         for(int y=0; y<n; y++)
         {
                 cin>>min[y];
                 cin>>max[y];
         }
         for(x=0; x<n; x++)
         {
                 a[x] = (min[x] + max[x])/2;
         }

         for(int a1=0; a1<n; a1++)
         {

             e[a1][0] = min[a1];
             e[a1][1] = min[a1]+1;
             e[a1][3] = max[a1]-1;
             e[a1][4] = max[a1];
         }
         for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
         {

            for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
            {   
                for(int l=1; l<=i+1; l++)
            {
                if(l!=1)
                 {
                    cout<<a[2]<<"\t";
                 }
            }
                cout<<e[i][j]<<"\t";
                for(int k=0; k<n-(i+1); k++)
                {
                    cout<<a[k]<<"\t";
                }
                cout<<"\n";
            }
        }    

        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. This answer contains only code. It would help if it also had some commentary or explanation. Thank you!